# Connect with iOS and Android clients to SockJS Backend

Tags: java, android, ios, spring, spring-websocket

I'm developing WebSocket messaging backend using [Spring WebSockets](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/), which uses SockJS + STOMP protocol. The reason why not to use plain WebSockets is because I will need to leverage security integration that SockJS provides in Spring WebSockets and also other neat features from SockJS, such as rooms, subscriptions, etc. I was wondering if this is a good option to use so that mobile (iOS and Android) and Web client apps can easily connect to the backend server and perform messaging. If yes, then what libraries I can use for iOS and Android.

On [SockJS GitHub page](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) they are also listing available client libraries, but no iOS nor Android. So, I'm wondering if SockJS is even worth to use just because of that.

I found that for iOS client [Primus-Objc](http://seegno.com/blog/2014/03/21/primus-objc-a-realtime-framework-agnostic-library-for-ios/) ([GitHub page](https://github.com/seegno/primus-objc)) library claiming that they can connect to `native WebSockets, Socket.IO, SockJS or perhaps engine.io.` is that a true statement? And event if that's true, what about the quality of that library?

And event if it is ok to use SockJS on the back, then would it be also possible to show an example code for iOS and Android so that I can perform a proof of concept on mobile devices?

If SockJS is not a good option for me, then would it be better than to build my messaging app with Socket.io + Node.js (using JavaScript). Socket.io seems to me have all needed client libraries for iOS ([official library by Socket.IO guys](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/)) and Android ([official library by Socket.IO guys](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)).

Another option can be to use [Netty-Socket.io](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) library and build each endpoint manually without any help from Spring Framework (which I'm considering to use) but there is small challenge that I'll have to tackle, that is security. [Somebody actually already tried to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294883/netty-socketio-with-spring-security) ([the same author asking question on the official Netty-Socket.IO Github page](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/issues/110)) but looks like he didn't have a luck in solving it yet.

Comment: refer this blog http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps

Comment: also, have a look on https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example

Comment: why not simply use cometd? It has support for Android as well...

Comment: If you want relevant cometd code, let me know. I have cometd implementation for my project.

Comment: Can you found the answer of this problem? Any Android client which works fine with SockJS back-end?

Comment: @YasirTahir Nope, didn't find anything, switched to SocketIO and been using it for almost 1.5 years now.

Comment: @Maksim 1. are you using the socket io with springboot and how did you achieve implementing an android client, ios client talking to the spring server. 2 to set up you socket io, did you create a nodejs socket server. 3. did you implement a java client of the springboot

Answer (score 18):

Maybe it's more than a year since the question was asked. But, because it's getting in the first results when Googling for SockJS+Android. So, I am posting my answer.

From my experience with a recent project I worked on, we were able to use a STOMP client - [like the one here](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid)- to connect to Spring Websocket backend from native Android app.

And from the browser, you can still use SockJS client to gain across browsers compatibility to websockets with fallback.

A note to mention that when using only STOMP client to connect to native websocket the URL will be something like **ws:**//mydomain/SockJSEndpoint/**websocket**, 
and when using SockJS client from the browser the URL will be like **http**://mydomain/SockJSEndpoint.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this !

Comment: Omg thank you so much! Spent days figuring out what's the correct websocket endpoint on a Spring Boot application. Couldn't find any information on adding "/websocket" in any documentations when I tried to implement my own WebSocket+STOMP library in Android!

Comment: Let's say you can't use those libraries. Is it possible to connect with `ws://...` and construct STOMP frames and use just websocket without any library

Answer (score 5):

Please find below useful references related to your requirement for both iOS and Android

1. http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps
2. https://www.cometchat.com/blog/ios-android-chat-mobile-sdk/
3. https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example

Comment: Are there any examples of SockJS and iOS talking to each other and the user is authenticated?

Comment: Link #1 is a blogpost related to the source code in Link #3. They are just doing simple "Hello World" example there. In Link #2 they are offering to use some 3rd party SDK. Need something concrete and official related to SockJS, Mobile devices, and Stomp protocol.

Answer (score 2):

We have tested them, both Android-client ([link](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid)) was given by @Amr K. Ismail and

this iOS-client ([link](https://github.com/WrathChaos/StompClientLib)) are suitable with Spring-SockJS-Server which has STOMP.

Answer (score 0):

SockJS may be interesting because it provides non-ws transports. Just using WebSockets may not be possible in all situations.

There is one cross-platform SockJs client of the [OpenFL project](http://www.openfl.org/):

https://github.com/jeremyfa/openfl-sockjs

Not tested how well it works, but at least for Android it's using JavaScript from inside WebView, so should be no different than JavaScript one. Again, it is not clear how tightly it is coupled with OpenFL, but the approach of using WebView and stock SockJS client could probably be re-used.